# Unable to resolve subtype with InvalidTypeIdException while reading classes generated from swagger in Java

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, jackson-databind, openapi-generator

Below is the openapi code using which classes are generated:

```
PipelineTask:
  anyOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/TranslationTask'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ASRTask'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/TTSTask'
  discriminator:
    propertyName: taskType
    mapping:
      translation: '#/components/schemas/TranslationTask'
      asr: '#/components/schemas/ASRTask'
      tts: '#/components/schemas/TTSTask'
      
PipelineTasks:
  type: array
  items:
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/PipelineTask'
    
TranslationTask:
  required:
    - taskType
  type: object
  properties:
    taskType:
      $ref: #/components/schemas/SupportedTasks

SupportedTasks:
  type: string
  enum:
    - translation
    - transliteration
    - tts
    - asr
    - document-layout
    - ocr
    - glossary
    - ner
    - txt-lang-detection
    - audio-lang-detection
  description: the category of model under which it has been released or trained
```

Below are the classes generated by the same:
PipelineTask:

```
package io.swagger.pipelinerequest;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
/**
* PipelineTask
*/
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
  property = "taskType")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TranslationTask.class, name = "translation"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ASRTask.class, name = "asr"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TTSTask.class, name = "tts")
})
public interface PipelineTask {

    SupportedTasks getTaskType();
}
```

TranslationTask:

```
package io.swagger.model;

import java.util.Objects;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import io.swagger.model.SupportedTasks;
import io.swagger.model.TranslationRequest;
import io.swagger.model.TranslationResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

/**
 * TranslationInference
 */
@Validated
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-03-02T03:55:25.562740452Z[GMT]")


public class TranslationInference  implements OneOfInferenceAPIEndPointSchema {
  @JsonProperty("taskType")
  private SupportedTasks taskType = null;

  @JsonProperty("request")
  private TranslationRequest request = null;

  @JsonProperty("response")
  private TranslationResponse response = null;

  public TranslationInference taskType(SupportedTasks taskType) {
    this.taskType = taskType;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get taskType
   * @return taskType
   **/
  @Schema(required = true, description = "")
      @NotNull

    @Valid
    public SupportedTasks getTaskType() {
    return taskType;
  }

  public void setTaskType(SupportedTasks taskType) {
    this.taskType = taskType;
  }

  public TranslationInference request(TranslationRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get request
   * @return request
   **/
  @Schema(required = true, description = "")
      @NotNull

    @Valid
    public TranslationRequest getRequest() {
    return request;
  }

  public void setRequest(TranslationRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
  }

  public TranslationInference response(TranslationResponse response) {
    this.response = response;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get response
   * @return response
   **/
  @Schema(description = "")
  
    @Valid
    public TranslationResponse getResponse() {
    return response;
  }

  public void setResponse(TranslationResponse response) {
    this.response = response;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    TranslationInference translationInference = (TranslationInference) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.taskType, translationInference.taskType) &&
        Objects.equals(this.request, translationInference.request) &&
        Objects.equals(this.response, translationInference.response);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(taskType, request, response);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class TranslationInference {\n");
    
    sb.append("    taskType: ").append(toIndentedString(taskType)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    request: ").append(toIndentedString(request)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    response: ").append(toIndentedString(response)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when running this:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class io.swagger.pipelinerequest.PipelineTask]: missing type id property 'type' (for POJO property 'pipelineTasks') at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 12, column: 9] (through reference chain: io.swagger.pipelinerequest.PipelineRequest["pipelineTasks"]->io.swagger.pipelinerequest.PipelineTasks[0])

Can anyone please help me resolve the same? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using CLI, maven plugin, or gradle plugin?  Also, which java library are you specifying?  Not every generator generates code the same way.  It's important to know which generator (Obviously `Java`) you are using as well as which library ('okHttp'?) you are using.  Also, which version of the generator are you using?  I ran the spring generator on 6.4.0 with your example and got completely different classes then you.  Please provide this information so I can help.  Finally, `anyOf` does not generate an Interface, `allOf` does.  Please provide the correct schema or generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try add the 'type' property into the payload?
'type' should be one of your sub-class name

ex: "type": "TranslationInference"

for me, it works